# HTML element not declaring id

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
$("#main-container").html("<div class='span12 category-container'>"+
   "<span class='color-line' id='coloredline'></span>"+
   "<span class='span11 cate-name' id='category-span'>"+this.category+"</span>"+
   "<span class='span11 comment-like-flag'>"+"<span class='span12 flag'>"+this.desc+"<span>"+
       "<span class='span12 flag'>"+
           "<img src=<c:url value='resources/img/postNeedIcons/flag-icons.png'/> class='flag-icon'/>"+
           "<span class='valuedigit'></span>"+
           "<span class='supportxt'>"+this.needCount+" people supported this need</span>"+
       "</span>"+
   "</span>"+
"</div>");
```

In above code `id='coloredline'` of `span` not showing in firebug.

Comment: i want to set color using jquery for this span . and i want it's id not class

Comment: It shows me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pSHDh/)! And what it has to do with ID?

Comment: check whether ('#main-container').html() is working.

Comment: Yes its working only this span is not showing id in firebug

Comment: You are simply not feeding jQuery with valid HTML: `<img src=<c:url value`. You can expect unexpected results.

Comment: All code working fine except one span element. <img src=<c:url value.this is the jsp tag

Answer (score 0):

The html you are generating has some error as

```
"<img src=<c:url value='resources/img/postNeedIcons/flag-icons.png'/> class='flag-icon'/>"
```

is not valid one

try to implement like :

```
"<img src='http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5519/10965435794_1f0feaf89e_m.jpg' class='flag-icon'  />"
```

For complete working example, refer to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/7Lvgw/3/)